# Como crear una barra flotante abajo de la pagina que se despliegue hacia arriba

Tags: javascript, html, css

Me gustaria que hubiera una barra en la parte de abajo de mi web y cuando yo clicase se desplegase un panel y hubiera un texto

HTML

```
 <div class="navbar">
    <button class="dropdown-btn">Menú</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Pruebas</a>
        <a href="#">Pruebas1</a>
        <a href="#">Pruebas2</a>
    </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.navbar {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.7); 
color: #fff;
border: 1px solid #444;
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 10px;
}
```

Estilo para el botón desplegable

```
.dropdown-btn {
background-color: #333;
color: #fff;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Estilo para el contenido desplegable

```
.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #333;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
z-index: 1;
}
```

Estilo para las opciones del menú

```
.dropdown-content a {
color: #fff;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
}
```

Estilo para el input y botón de añadir información

```
.info-input {
padding: 10px;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}
```

Mostrar el menú desplegable cuando se pasa el ratón sobre el botón

```
.navbar:hover .dropdown-content {
display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

esto fue lo mas parecido que pude hacer con la ayuda de varias paginas, espero que te sirva

> html

```
    <footer>
    <div class="menu" id="menu">
    <nav id="navega"><ul >
    <li><a href="#">prueba 1</a>   </li>
    <li><a href="#">prueba 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">prueba 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">prueba 1</a></li>
        
    </ul></nav>
    Menu
    
    </div>
    </footer>
```

> Css

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);
* {
  
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

body {
   font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  
}


nav {
  
  width:100%;
     max-height:0px;
  overflow:hidden;
  transition: 1s all; 
 
}
.mostrar {
      max-height:500px;
 
 
 
}
nav ul {
  
  list-style:none;
  display: flex;
  width:100%;
}
nav ul li{
  margin-right: 30px;
  width: 20%;
}
nav ul li a{
  
  
 text-decoration:none;
  display:flex;
  line-height:50px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #222;
  background-color:#03EBA6;
  color:#222;
  font-size:1.2em;
  padding:10px;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  
  
  background-color:#222;
  color:#fff;
}

.menu {
  
  padding:20px;
  background-color:#222;
  color:#fff;
  width:15%;
  cursor:pointer;  
 position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
}
footer{
  position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
}
```

> Js

```
document.getElementById("menu").addEventListener("click",function(){
  
  document.getElementById("navega").classList.toggle("mostrar");
});
```

```js
document.getElementById("menu").addEventListener("click",function(){
  
  document.getElementById("navega").classList.toggle("mostrar");
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);
* {
  
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

body {
   font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  
}


nav {
  
  width:100%;
     max-height:0px;
  overflow:hidden;
  transition: 1s all; 
 
}
.mostrar {
      max-height:500px;
 
 
 
}
nav ul {
  
  list-style:none;
  display: flex;
  width:100%;
}
nav ul li{
  margin-right: 30px;
  width: 20%;
}
nav ul li a{
  
  
 text-decoration:none;
  display:flex;
  line-height:50px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #222;
  background-color:#03EBA6;
  color:#222;
  font-size:1.2em;
  padding:10px;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  
  
  background-color:#222;
  color:#fff;
}

.menu {
  
  padding:20px;
  background-color:#222;
  color:#fff;
  width:15%;
  cursor:pointer;  
 position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
}
footer{
  position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="menu" id="menu">
    <nav id="navega"><ul >
    <li><a href="#">prueba 1</a>   </li>
    <li><a href="#">prueba 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">prueba 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">prueba 1</a></li>
    
  </ul></nav>
Menu

  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Me sirve eso graciass